# Testing ListView with Espresso by finding its objects within the adapter

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have a custom matcher used to test that some data exists in a ListView.
It find all the objects kept by the listview adapter:

```
private static Matcher<Object> checkStringInList(final Matcher<String> expected) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, MyObject>(MyObject.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final MyObject actualObject) {
            return expected.matches(actualObject.getDisplayName());
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("row with string " + expected.toString() + " was not found!");
        }
    };
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
onData(allOf(instanceOf(MyObject.class), checkStringInList(equalTo("Teams")))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

The above test will pass. Alright!

BUT the weird thing happens when I pass a string which doesn't exist within the list and I really want to check that it's not existing

```
onData(allOf(instanceOf(MyObject.class), checkStringInList(equalTo("TeamsSSS")))).check(doesNotExist());
```

The strange error is:

```
    android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView'.
    at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:81)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:167)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:110)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: (an instance of com.test.me.datamodel.MyObject and row with string "TeamsSSS" was not found!)
```

I already know that the string will not exist and I'm checking for that, but why it doesn't pass if so?

Does it matter if my list is an ExpandableListView? It is also a descendant from android.widget.AdapterView.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another matcher that checks if the item is not in the list.

Likely, espresso authors provided a [sample](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes.html#asserting-data-item-not-in-adapter) just for that.

Here is the matcher from that link:

```
private static Matcher<View> withAdaptedData(final Matcher<Object> dataMatcher) {
return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with class name: ");
        dataMatcher.describeTo(description);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
        if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
            return false;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Adapter adapter = ((AdapterView) view).getAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            if (dataMatcher.matches(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
}
```

and the usage:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.list))
      .check(matches(not(withAdaptedData(withItemContent("item: 168")))));
```